# getInitialProps() should resolve to an object. But found "undefined" instead

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase to my next.js application using getInitialProps but the data shows up in the VS Code terminal (along with some errors). However, in the browser, I get this message

[image: getInitialProps() should resolve to an object. But found "undefined" instead]

Please check the code

```
// Other import code
import { firestore } from "../firebase/firebase.utils";

const Hotels = (props) => {
  return (
    // jsx code
  );
};

Hotels.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  let hotelsRef = firestore.collection("hotels");
  let query = hotelsRef
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
        return;
      }

      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        return { props: doc.data() };
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
};

export default Hotels;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should return from object from `getInitialProps` , but in your case you are not returning anything and also not making any use of `async await`

Here you go :

```
Hotels.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    let hotelsRef = firestore.collection("hotels");
    let snapshot = await hotelsRef.get()
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log("No matching documents.");
        return;
    }
    let data = []
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        data.push(doc.data());
    });
    return { props : data };
};
```

Comment: Now I got the error message "snapshot.map is not a function", so I used forEach but that returns `{ props: undefined }` in VS Code terminal (empty array in chrome console).

Comment: So snapshot is not array,please check its value and return it, I have just converted it to as per your code, so your main issue is resolved please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: I am not getting any value in the array anymore. It's empty.

Comment: cleaned the snippet - there was an extra {

Comment: I am only getting results in my vs code console and not in the props. Do you know why?

Comment: @iDev, whats the result you are getting in vscode?will you please share that?

Comment: I get the results from firestore db. FeyBZi6bnaJ6EDyksX8D => {
  title: 'Hotel Clinton Park Inn',
  facilities: [
    'Stylish Multicuisine Restaurant',
    'The Lounge Bar',
    'Banquet Hall',
    'Board Room',
    'Doctor on Call'
  ],
// and so on
I get this result only in VS Code terminal

Comment: is it out put of `console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());` inside `snapshot.map`?